# Error when installing uberproxy/phpclient using composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm getting the below error when trying to install uberproxy/phpclient using composer via `composer require uberproxy/phpclient`

> [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                            Could not find package uberproxy/php-client at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability`

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Do you really want to add software that is unmaintained for two years now and hasn't had at least one tagged release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out. I changed the minimum stability setting in the `composer.json` file to read as below

```
{
"minimum-stability": "dev",
 }
```

I was then able to run `composer require uberproxy/phpclient` without running into any errors.